# SQL Query - Search with SQL array results

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying this query to get result. but am not able to find any results. I don't know where i did the mistake.

```
Select * from loadcell_transaction_log where id = 

(SELECT  max(id) as id1
  FROM [addpro].[dbo].[loadcell_transaction_log] group by line2_count);
```

This is the error am getting:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The query you posted is not MySQL. Also the error message. They are probably MSSQL. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * from loadcell_transaction_log where id IN

(SELECT  max(id) as id1
  FROM [addpro].[dbo].[loadcell_transaction_log] group by line2_count);
```

I replace '=' with the keyword 'IN' which allows for multiple results in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

using group by with max(id) will return max(id) for each line2_count :

```
select * from 
  (select log.*,row_number() over (partition by line2_count order by id desc ) rn FROM [addpro].[dbo].[loadcell_transaction_log] as log)
  where rn = 1;
```

If you want to check only for max(id) in the full table data then dont use group by clause else use in clause as referred by @farbiondriven.

Comment: Probably because you just make a comment and say what has already been answered. Duplicating answers makes no sense, you should perhaps find a different solution and people will not downvote.

Comment: that makes sense. Before someone answers, I had already typed my answer so just posted it. Will keep in mind next time. :)

Comment: Perhaps just change the answer to something a little different than the first answer so it is a second option.

Comment: There you go. Downvote retracted and you gained a vote.

Comment: This encouraged me to write more answers :D

Comment: Now that is more like it!!